# What's the correct way to load .otf font files in webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webpack, webpack-file-loader

What is the appropriate way to load .otf font files when using webpack? I have made several attempts to include a rule in my `webpack.config.js`, without any success, based on many examples I've seen along the lines of the following:

```
{ test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|otf|woff)$/, use: 'file-loader' }
//or
{ test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|otf|woff)$/, use: 'url-loader' }
//or
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, use: 'file-loader' }
//...etc
```

I've set up in my `webpack.config.js` the following for other file types, which are working successfully:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
      module: {
        rules: [
          { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
          { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]},
          { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|xml)$/i, use: 'file-loader'}
        ]
      },
    //...
}
```

Despite my various attempts to add another rule/case for .otf files, I always get the following error:

> Module parse failed: .../fonts/[name-of-my-font].otf Unexpected character '
> ' (1:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I've added the .otf file in a `fonts` folder in my root directory, and in my index.css I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'name-of-my-font';
  src: url('fonts/name-of-my-font.otf'),
  format('opentype');
}
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution for this?

Per comment request for more of my `webpack.config.js` file, here is my entire `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]},
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|xml)$/i, use: 'file-loader' }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Can you share your full `module.loaders`  from your webpack config ?

Comment: @Bulkan I've amended my question to include my full `webpack.config.js` at the end. Does this help?

Comment: are you sure you have the url-loader and file-loader installed?

Comment: @MudiagaEjenavi Thanks for your question. I've checked and both file-loader and url-loader are installed. Do you have any suggestion for if (and how) these both should be specified in my webpack.config.js? Or might something else be causing the error I'm receiving?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added

```
  {    
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
    loader: "file-loader"
  }
```

to my webpack.config.js.
I think I needed to explicitly link the types to the file-loader. I was using the default VS2017 Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

In my **webpack.config.js** I have:

```
{
  test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
  use: "file-loader"
}
```

Then in my **index.js** file I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';
import avenir from '../font/AvenirLTStd-Light.otf';
injectGlobal`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Avenir';
        src: url(${avenir}) format('opentype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    * {
        font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
    }
`;

import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  , document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Using the injectGlobal helper from the styled-components library will automatically inject the styles into your css file. You can probably move the styled-components stuff to a separate .js file then import it.